# How do I insert values into empty tables that have foreign keys attached to them?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have several tables which I just created, a lot of them referencing each other with their foreign keys. I just created them so they're all empty in sql server 2012.

```
CREATE TABLE Candidate
(
candidateId         int         primary key,
qualificationId     int         NOT NULL,
trainingSessionId   int         NOT NULL,
prerequesiteId      int         NOT NULL,
courseId            int         NOT NULL,
qualification       nvarchar(20),
jobHistoryId        int         NOT NULL,
name                nvarchar(20)
)

INSERT INTO Candidate
values (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 'plumer', 1, 'jordan')
```

I want to do something like that but I get this error

```
The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK__Candidate__quali__29572725". The conflict occurred in database "TEC", table "dbo.Qualifications", column 'qualificationId'.
```

My qualification table is

```
CREATE TABLE Qualifications
(
qualificationId int primary key,
name nvarchar(20)
)
```

And i have other tables like

```
CREATE TABLE TrainingSession
(
trainingSessionId int primary key,
candidateId int foreign key references Candidate(candidateId),
courseId int NOT NULL,
prerequesiteId int NOT NULL,
qualificationId int NOT NULL,
trainingName nvarchar(20)
)
```

and like I said alot of them reference each other.

So how do I insert values into these tables when I get that error?

Edit: after I created all the tables I altered them to add the foreign keys that were not already there like

```
ALTER TABLE Candidate
ADD FOREIGN KEY (qualificationId)
REFERENCES Qualifications(qualificationId) 

ALTER TABLE Candidate
ADD FOREIGN KEY (trainingSessionId)
REFERENCES TrainingSession(trainingSessionId)
```

Edit 2: I try and insert into Candidate, I get the error above, I try to inset into Training Session, I get the same error but in Candidate

```
The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK__TrainingS__candi__173876EA". The conflict occurred in database "TEC", table "dbo.Candidate", column 'candidateId'.
```

Comment: Are you using MySQL or SQL Server? They aren't the same thing.

Comment: @JohnConde sorry im using sql server, i just updated the tags

Comment: That is why you have the foreign key constraint to give you the error that your receiving. You would need to insert  a row in Qualifications, TrainingSession etc. before you can insert in Candidate. That the whole point of Foreign keys. SO what is your question again?

Comment: @TMNT2014 I inserted values in to Qualifications fine, but when I try and insert into TrainingSession I get a similar error, I think its because of all the inter connecting foreign keys

Comment: @TMNT2014 You haven't really understood the crux of the matter here. The primary key of each table has been defined as the foreign key of another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's something I don't understand about your database design. Look at this:

```
CREATE TABLE Candidate
(
    candidateId         int         primary key,
    qualificationId     int         NOT NULL,
    trainingSessionId   int         NOT NULL,  /* Does  this reference TrainingSession?*/
    prerequesiteId      int         NOT NULL,
    courseId            int         NOT NULL,
    qualification       nvarchar(20),
    jobHistoryId        int         NOT NULL,
    name                nvarchar(20)
)

CREATE TABLE TrainingSession
(
    trainingSessionId int primary key,
    candidateId int foreign key references Candidate(candidateId),
    courseId int NOT NULL,
    prerequesiteId int NOT NULL,
    qualificationId int NOT NULL,
    trainingName nvarchar(20)
)
```

They both seem to be referencing each other which seems weird to me and not right. There should ideally be just one reference between them.

Also, if the `TrainingSessionId` in the `Candidate` table is not a foreign key, then why is it there? You can always get its value via a join query. Isn't that a reason why `CandidateID` is a foreign key in the `TrainingSession` table?

**UPDATE**:

The problem you are having is that :

"You need a `TrainingSesssionId` value in the `TrainingSession` table to insert a row in `Candidate` table. Since you don't have one, it gives you a foreign key constraint error. Similarly, you need a `CandidateId` value in the `Candidate` table to insert a row in `TrainingSession` table. So that also gives you a foreign key constraint error. There's no escaping this. Hence, this design is flawed.

What you can do is:

Remove the `TrainingsessionId` column from the `Candidate` table **OR** remove the `CandidateId` column from the `TrainingSession` table. The point is you need to remove one of these foreign key references. Which one? That depends on your particular scenario's and use-cases. But the main point here is that **you'll have to drop one of these foreign key references**. Its redundant anyways. *You need just one foreign key to create a relationship between two tables*. Due to the existence of a (note:single) foreign key, you can relate between two tables and fetch values from either tables based on the foreign key. There is simply no need to have another foreign key.

Secondly, since `Qualifications` has no foreign key reference, in this context it seems to be like a master table. So, insertion begins here. Then, you'd have to insert in `Candidate` table (in case `TrainingSessionId` is not a foreign key in this table) and then in the `TrainingSession` table.

Hope this helps!!!

Comment: I have trainingsessionid as a foreign key in my Candidate table, I had to create the Training Session table first and then I altered my Candidate table. I inserted values into my Qualifications fine, but I can't for other tables where foreign keys are referencing each other.

Comment: @user2981393 Thats exactly the point I make. Since they are foreign keys to each other, one cannot have a value in it before the other has a value. Its a classical **chicken or egg** situation now.

Comment: So my database design is flawed? I am a novice in creating databases, what would be a solution?

Comment: @user2981393 You need a `TrainingSesssionId` value in the `TrainingSession` table to insert a row in `Candidate` table. Since you don't have one, it gives you a foreign key constraint error. Similarly, You need a `CandidateId` value in the `Candidate` table to insert a row in `TrainingSession` table. SO that also gives you a foreign key constraint error.  There's no escaping this. Hence, the flawed design.

Comment: @user2981393 You can remove the `TrainingsessionId` column from the `Candidate` table **OR** remove the `CandidateId` column from the `TrainingSession` table. The point is you need to remove one of these foreign key references. Which one? *That depends on your particular scenario's and use-cases.*

Comment: Could I use an auto increment key word to solve this? or do I have to redesign my database

Comment: @user2981393 The point is **You'll have to drop one of these foreign key references**. Its redundant anyways. You need just one foreign key to create a relationship between two tables.

Comment: @user2981393 Due to the existence of a (note:single) foreign key, you can relate between two tables and fetch values from either tables based on the foreign key. There is simply no need to have another foreign key.

Comment: @user2981393 Auto-increment would not serve the purpose. It will just create a column which will have no use. Why create a column which you have no use of? Right?

Comment: Ah ok 'You need just one foreign key to create a relationship between two tables' makes sense. thanks